# Reading multiple text files from a directory and add its columns into one text file in R

Tags: r

I have multiple files in a directory and what I need to achieve is to concatenate(What I mean here is to add columns from other text files into one file) all those text files into one DataFrame. And the final dataframe should contain multiple number of column(same  as the number of text files in the directory).
For example,
file_1 looks like this

```
id      pool1
ABL1    1352
ABL12   1236
ABL13   1022
ABL14   815
ABL15   1591
ABL16   2703
```

And so as the other files the first column is same for all other files in the directory and second columns are different.

I am looking for a output which looks something like this,

```
 id /pool1  /pool2  /pool3  /pool4  /pool5
ABL1    1352    1353    1354    1355    1356
ABL12   1236    1237    1238    1239    1240
ABL13   1022    1023    1024    1025    1026
ABL14   815      816    817      818    819
ABL15   1591    1592    1593    1594    1595
ABL16   2703    2704    2705    2706    2707
ABL17   1449    1450    1451    1452    1453
ABL18   619     620     621      622    623
ABL19   1074    1075    1076    1077    1078
```

So far I was trying to achieve it in R via following scripts,

```
  lf <- list.files(path = "path/files", pattern = ".txt_samplecount$", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, include.dirs = TRUE)
dat <- setNames( lapply(lf, read.table, sep="\t", header=TRUE), lf)
```

But I could find that this above piece script is merging the columns as to one file and the final dat file is still having only two columns.

Any help or suggestions are welcome

Thank you

Comment: youcould try `unstack`ing your two column thing, `unstack(dat, pool ~ id)`, or extact the second column of each table in your `lapply` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat) #data containing ids
lapply(lf,function(x){
   y<-fread(lf)
   nm<-names(y)[2]
   dat[y,(nm):=get(nm),on="id"]})
```

More robust (if any of `lf` contain more than one column) would be:

```
lapply(lf,function(x){
       y<-fread(lf)
       nm<-setdiff(names(y),"id")
       dat[y,(nm):=mget(nm),on="id"]})
```

Even more robust (allowing that you might have multiple files in `lf` that have a column named `pool1`, e.g.) would be:

```
lapply(lf,function(x){
       y<-fread(lf)
       nm<-setdiff(names(y),"id")
       if (length(intersect(nm,names(dat)))){
         nm_dup<-intersect(nm,names(dat))
         nm_new<-setdiff(nm,nm_dup)
         dat[y,(nm_new):=mget(nm_new),on="id"]
         dat[y,paste0(nm_dup,z):=mget(paste0("i.",nm_dup)),on="id"]
       }else dat[y,(nm):=mget(nm),on="id"]})
```

Where `z` is some unique identifier for each file in `lf`, perhaps the first 4 characters of the file name, etc.

Comment: Hello Thank you for the solution..But with three of those robust solutions I am still having error to get the results.. As I have the following error message,  Error in fread(lf) : 
  'input' must be a single character string containing a file name, a command, full path to a file, a URL starting 'http://' or 'file://', or the input data itself

Comment: @user1017373 you need to make sure `lf` is indeed a list of file names, including extensions.